# Android: Inserting Arraylist values into database

Tags: android, database, arraylist

Hi can someone point me in right direction how to insert arraylist values into database. i have two arraylist as below:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> achieve_val = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> achieve_vol = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> Achiev_Vol_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     Achiev_Vol_map.put(PRODUCT_CAKE, Achieve_Vcake);
     Achiev_Vol_map.put(PRODUCT_YEASTEXTRACT, Achieve_Vyeastextract);
     .
     .
     .
     achieve_vol.add(Achiev_Vol_map);
```

i created a POJO class for this values as below:

```
    public class ProductCategory {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> achieve_val,achieve_vol ;

         public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAchieve_val() {
            return achieve_val;}
        public void setAchieve_val(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> achieve_val) {
            this.achieve_val = achieve_val;}

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAchieve_vol() {
            return achieve_vol;}
        public void setAchieve_vol(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> achieve_vol) {
            this.achieve_vol = achieve_vol;}

/**my constructor**/
        public ProductCategory(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> achieve_val,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> achieve_vol) {
            super();
            this.achieve_val = achieve_val;
           this.achieve_vol = achieve_vol;}}
```

I am passing this values to my database adapter as below

```
dbHelper.open();
dbHelper.topinchartsRecord(new ProductCategory(achieve_val,achieve_vol));
```

Now in my database adpater i am not sure how to access those vlaues and insert in database , done somethin as below:

```
public void topinchartsRecord(ProductCategory productCategory) {

    for(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> map : achieve_val){
           ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
           cv.put(FILE_NAME, map.get(FILE_NAME));

           db.insert("tablename", null, cv);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method Hope this help you

```
public void insertRecords(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data,
            String tableName) {
        if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {

            ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
            db.beginTransaction();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                con.clear();
                HashMap<String, String> row = data.get(i);
                Iterator<String> it = row.keySet().iterator();

                while (it.hasNext()) {

                    String columnName = it.next();
                    con.put(columnName, row.get(columnName));
                }

                db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, con,
                        SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
```

**From your Method**

```
public void topinchartsRecord(ProductCategory productCategory) {

        try{
            insertRecords(productCategory.getAchieve_val(),"tableNameForThisValues");
            insertRecords(productCategory.getAchieve_vol(),"tableNameForThisValues");
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

Pass ArrayList of Hashmap to this method and name of table will insert into database.

Comment: Hi do i need to put the your method in my topincharts method? how do i  call your method

Comment: Hi , i dont see any data in my table, its not inserting, do i need to change this  String columnName = it.next();
                    con.put(columnName, row.get(columnName)); ???or ....

Comment: except this 09-25 06:54:37.351: E/SQLiteLog(21272): (1) near "-": syntax error  ,no other error, but app is running

Comment: make this datefield datatype to "TEXT" instead of "DATE"

Comment: Its is TEXT now...actually it has to read and insert  this value ("Yeast - Nutriferm / Cell wall":" - ",). when i am printing in log i am getting the value as '-' ,but itz not entering in database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38000/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-teekib)

Comment: @Biraj..hi u there?can we discuss now..sorry for late network problem